# Delete data from database on an aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying delete data from a database on an aspx page. When I do this I get the following errors are:

- name litTitleName doesn't exist in current context
- name litDatePosted doesn't exist in current context
- name litNewscontent doesn't exist in current contest

The delete.aspx page is configured as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Please confirm you wish to delete the following news item</p>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <asp:Literal ID="litTitleName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>
            From:
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>
            <asp:Literal ID="litNews" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            (<asp:Literal ID="litEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:Literal>)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete" tabindex="1" class="form-control btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
        <a href="/Backend/Default.aspx" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The delete.aspx.cs page is configured as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string q = Request.QueryString["id"];
        int.TryParse(q, out int id);

        if (Session["username"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            DeleteNews(id);
            Response.Redirect("~/Backend");
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateNews(id);
        }
    }

    private void DeleteNews(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        string query = "DELETE FROM News WHERE [Id] = @id";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

    private void PopulateNews(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT Title, DatePosted, Newscontent FROM News WHERE Id = @id";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            litTitleName.Text = reader["Title"].ToString();
            litDatePosted.Text = reader["DatePosted"].ToString();
            litNewscontent.Text = reader["Newscontent"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

The database table is configured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[DatePosted]  DATE           NOT NULL,
[NewsContent] NTEXT          NOT NULL,
[IsRead]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: I think you should need to end your response. So try this instead `Response.Redirect("~/Backend", true);` 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: MSDN says «calling redirect is same as calling redirect with True as second parameter». So it will have no effect @KundanSinghChouhan

Answer (score 0):

> Note: FYI, You are just redirecting to **~/Backend**, missing extension

Other than above point, there seems nothing wrong with your code. If you are able to refer `literals` by name in codebehind then it should work.

I have also faced similar issue sometimes and the issue is something not programming error BUT human error (*happens usually when I copy existing aspx instead of creating new*).

Try **Clean** and **Rebuild** from *visual studio* before doing anything else.

If you still get error See following for `delete.aspx` page;

1. Check the `Inherits` attribute of `aspx` page. It should have correct namespace as used in **codebehind** file.
2. Check `codebehind` attribute of `page` in `aspx` file, is it referring to correct codebehind file!!

> There are though some code changes that you can do to follow common code flow of asp.net programming. But that has nothing to do with the error you are facing. Like using `<asp:Button`, using `using{}` for `SqlDataReader`, etc

Comment: You were, I copied it in wrong, Started from scratch and it worked perfectly. Thanks a million for your help. Much appreciated.